# tiles missing within bounding box in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

Created map with leaflet js. Added osm as basemap with the attributes as below:

```
var osm_base_map = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
});
```

The map is working fine. But the problem is, some tiles are missing from the right side of the map when I am panning the base map as I marked with the attached image.
I am expecting to load all the tiles within the bounding box.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: You should obfuscate your Mapbox access token.

Comment: Do those tiles load if you move the map to the right?